# How to click certain button using Selenium Python xpath ?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrap a web site News list after searching a certain word. But I can't figure out how to access News list.

First of all, I entered a key work and click search button.

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("query") 
elem.send_keys("kpop")    
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("search_btn")
elem.click()
```

The result page is this: https://search.naver.com/search.naver?sm=tab_hty.top&where=nexearch&query=kpop&oquery=kpop&tqi=To2nllpySEKsssnbxrsssssssFd-407861

And I want to move on News tab placed on third tab
[image: News tab]

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *url* you have shared to click on the link to move on to the **News** tab placed on third tab you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='base']/li[@class='lnb4']/a[@class='tab']/span[@class='spnew']").click()
```

You may require to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *webelement* to be clickable as follows :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='base']/li[@class='lnb4']/a[@class='tab']/span[@class='spnew']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the desired element. Copy the xpath. Paste it in `.find_element_by_xpath()`.

`button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nx_search_form"]/fieldset/button`')

Comment: I'm new to Python..so can you explain how can i find 'nx_search_form'? I did copy the xpath, but I don't know where to find 'nx_search_form'

Comment: Not sure I follow you. You don't know where to find the element you want?  If you are looking to scrape just the news info you could add your keyword to the href and skip the form all together. `url = "https://search.naver.com/search.naver?where=news&sm=tab_jum&query="+your_search_term`